# Four videos on a page, slows down browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

Videos are around 30 seconds long 15mbs, is it possible to have them on a page or should I switch to cover images, I want to use the video as separator smilier to http://themeforest.net/item/luv-responsive-wedding-event-wordpress-theme/full_screen_preview/9410071

Do anyone have any advice or recommendation

Comment: Make them seriously smaller, load only one at once or drop them. 30 seconds is way too long, and if they weren't HD and encoded carefully you could probably get them much smaller.

Comment: Questions must be specific technical questions only. This is way too open ended.  Don't ask for recommendations on stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

A good idea would be to make the videos compressed to their max (like smallest dimensions and framerate while maintaining quality).

If you can, defer the load of the videos until after page load (jquery or javascript) by setting the url of the video after load. What about loading an iframe? This question could be help: [should embedding video in home page slow down the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/917535/should-embedding-video-in-home-page-slow-down-the-page/917646#917646)

You could also stream the video.

Or you can make a cover image, as you said, and load it when the user clicks on it. That could be done something like this:

```
<video width="520" height="300" poster="link to the cover image" controls>
    <source src="link to the video" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```